# Are the groups $G:=\{A \in M(n,\mathbb R) : A=A^t\}$ i.e. the group ( under addition ) of symmetric matrices and $O(n,\mathbb R)$ isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, orthogonal-matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $G:=\{A \in M(n,\mathbb R) : A=A^t\}$ i.e. the group ( under addition ) of symmetric matrices ; Are $G$ and $O(n,\mathbb R)$ isomorphic ?

Comment: Are you sure that you want G to be the group of symmetric matrices and not the group of skew-symmetric matrices?

Comment: @user44400 : umm yes . Why ? Is the group of skew symmetric matrices isomorphic with the group of orthogonal matrices ?

Comment: This comment does not answer your question, but it shows that the group of skew-symmetric matrices and the orthogonal matrices are naturally related: The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{o}(n)$ of the orthogonal group $O(n)$ consists of the skew-symmetric matrices.

There is a map $\exp : \mathfrak{o}(n) \to O(n)$ sending a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ to $\exp(A) := \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{A^i}{i!}$. This is a group homomorphism, but it is not surjective, since there are orthogonal matrices with determinant -1, but $\det(\exp A) = 1$ for $A \in \mathfrak{o}(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, for every $n\ge1$. In $G$, if $A$ is not the identity element, so is not $A+A$. In $O(n,\mathbb R)$, however, there exists some $A$ such that $A^2$ is the identity element but $A$ isn't.

Answer (score 2):

No, $G$ is abelian while $O(n,\Bbb R)$ is not.

Comment: (The above is for $n\geq 2$. If $n=1$ it is clear also since $G=\Bbb R$ and $O(1,\Bbb R)=\{\pm 1\}$.)